# Oracle / SQL command for showing only rows where criteria is changed

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, oracle

my database looks like this (ordered by `DATETIME`):

[image]

My problem is that there a thousands of entries, but I only need the rows where the `Pumpe1_1` is changed from `FALSE` to `TRUE` or from `TRUE` to `FALSE`. So in this example I just need two rows (green marked):

[image]

The next row I need is when the `Pumpe1_1` changes back to `FALSE`.

My SQL statement so far is

```
SELECT DATETIME, TOTALTIME1, RAWOUTPUT1, 
CASE BITAND(RAWOUTPUT1, POWER(2,0)) WHEN 0 THEN 'FALSE' ELSE 'TRUE' END AS Pumpe1_1 FROM pump_box_hist
```

My only idea is to loop throw the entries (when sent to a datatable in c#) if the `Pumpe1_1` is changed or is there a better and faster way to do this directly on the database? Thanks!

**Edit for the answer from San:**

I added in your solution my old snippet with the TRUE/FALSE:

```
WITH table_ AS ( 
  SELECT DATETIME, TOTALTIME1, RAWOUTPUT1, 
         LEAD (RAWOUTPUT1) OVER (ORDER BY datetime) next_,
         LAG (RAWOUTPUT1) OVER (ORDER BY datetime) priv_, 
        CASE BITAND(RAWOUTPUT1, POWER(2,0)) WHEN 0 THEN 'FALSE' ELSE 'TRUE' END AS Pumpe1_1
    FROM pump_box_hist)
SELECT DATETIME, TOTALTIME1, RAWOUTPUT1, Pumpe1_1
  FROM table_
 WHERE (RAWOUTPUT1 != next_ OR RAWOUTPUT1 != priv_);
```

But it seems that it only works if the `RAWOUTPUT1` is changed, the result:

```
DATETIME                  TOTALTIME1             RAWOUTPUT1             PUMPE1_1 
------------------------- ---------------------- ---------------------- -------- 
30.10.14                  52037                  0                      FALSE    
30.10.14                  52037                  1                      TRUE     
30.10.14                  52037                  1                      TRUE     
30.10.14                  52037                  3                      TRUE     
30.10.14                  52037                  3                      TRUE     
30.10.14                  52361                  1                      TRUE     
30.10.14                  52361                  1                      TRUE     
30.10.14                  53848                  0                      FALSE    
30.10.14                  53848                  0                      FALSE    
30.10.14                  53848                  1                      TRUE     
30.10.14                  53848                  1                      TRUE     
30.10.14                  54693                  4                      FALSE    
30.10.14                  54693                  4                      FALSE    
30.10.14                  54693                  6                      FALSE
```

So the goal is to get the duplicates of TRUE/FALSE out to get this result (only rows when TRUE/FALSE changes):

```
DATETIME                  TOTALTIME1             RAWOUTPUT1             PUMPE1_1 
------------------------- ---------------------- ---------------------- -------- 
30.10.14                  52037                  0                      FALSE    
30.10.14                  52037                  1                      TRUE       
30.10.14                  53848                  0                      FALSE    
30.10.14                  53848                  1                      TRUE         
30.10.14                  54693                  4                      FALSE
```

Thanks again!

**Update 2:**

Again what learned, did't know that I need a second table like in your script, that answered why my tries failed with changing the `LAG / LEAD` with the `Pumpe1_1`...

I converted the date to see where still the problem is.
This is the output of your script:

```
Converted Time          DATETIME                  TOTALTIME1             RAWOUTPUT1             PUMPE1_1 
----------------------- ------------------------- ---------------------- ---------------------- -------- 
Do 30-Okt-2014 11:23:24 30.10.14                  52037                  0                      FALSE    
Do 30-Okt-2014 11:23:39 30.10.14                  52037                  1                      TRUE     
Do 30-Okt-2014 11:48:23 30.10.14                  52361                  1                      TRUE     
Do 30-Okt-2014 11:48:37 30.10.14                  53848                  0                      FALSE    
Do 30-Okt-2014 12:53:20 30.10.14                  53848                  0                      FALSE    
Do 30-Okt-2014 12:53:34 30.10.14                  53848                  1                      TRUE     
Do 30-Okt-2014 13:07:23 30.10.14                  53848                  1                      TRUE     
Do 30-Okt-2014 13:07:38 30.10.14                  54693                  4                      FALSE    
Do 30-Okt-2014 14:36:40 30.10.14                  55288                  20                     FALSE    
Do 30-Okt-2014 14:36:58 30.10.14                  55288                  17                     TRUE     
Do 30-Okt-2014 15:02:16 30.10.14                  55288                  17                     TRUE
```

The input is:

```
Converted Time          DATETIME                  TOTALTIME1             RAWOUTPUT1             PUMPE1_1 
----------------------- ------------------------- ---------------------- ---------------------- -------- 
Do 30-Okt-2014 11:22:55 30.10.14                  52037                  0                      FALSE    
Do 30-Okt-2014 11:23:10 30.10.14                  52037                  0                      FALSE    
Do 30-Okt-2014 11:23:24 30.10.14                  52037                  0                      FALSE     
Do 30-Okt-2014 11:23:39 30.10.14                  52037                  1                      TRUE     
Do 30-Okt-2014 11:23:53 30.10.14                  52037                  1                      TRUE     
....
Do 30-Okt-2014 11:48:08 30.10.14                  52361                  1                      TRUE     
Do 30-Okt-2014 11:48:23 30.10.14                  52361                  1                      TRUE     
Do 30-Okt-2014 11:48:37 30.10.14                  53848                  0                      FALSE    
Do 30-Okt-2014 11:48:52 30.10.14                  53848                  0                      FALSE    
....  
Do 30-Okt-2014 12:52:51 30.10.14                  53848                  0                      FALSE    
Do 30-Okt-2014 12:53:05 30.10.14                  53848                  0                      FALSE    
Do 30-Okt-2014 12:53:20 30.10.14                  53848                  0                      FALSE    
Do 30-Okt-2014 12:53:34 30.10.14                  53848                  1                      TRUE     
Do 30-Okt-2014 12:53:49 30.10.14                  53848                  1                      TRUE  
....
```

So when the `Pumpe1_1` changes from `TRUE` to `FALSE` or in the other direction the output takes also the row before it changes. Example:
11:23:39 changes from `FALSE` to `TRUE` but I also get the row before with is still `FALSE`. No idea why...

Comment: Do you need both MySQL and Oracle solution?

Comment: The problem is that it looks like your table contains a lot of duplicate rows (same date, totaltime etc.)

Comment: @jarlh I just need oracle, this is not my hole database so it's looks like duplicates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Oracle, you can use combination of lead and lag analytical functions to get your desired results:

```
WITH table_ AS ( 
  SELECT DATETIME, TOTALTIME1, RAWOUTPUT1,
         LEAD (RAWOUTPUT1) OVER (ORDER BY datetime) next_,
         LAG (RAWOUTPUT1) OVER (ORDER BY datetime) priv_
    FROM pump_box_hist)
SELECT DATETIME, TOTALTIME1, RAWOUTPUT1
  FROM table_
 WHERE (RAWOUTPUT1 != next_ OR RAWOUTPUT1 != priv_);
```

Update: Based on your input, there is a small change in the query to get what you are looking for. Let me know if it works

```
WITH table_ AS ( 
  SELECT DATETIME, TOTALTIME1, RAWOUTPUT1, 
         CASE BITAND(RAWOUTPUT1, POWER(2,0)) WHEN 0 THEN 'FALSE' ELSE 'TRUE' END AS Pumpe1_1
    FROM pump_box_hist),
table2_ AS (
  SELECT DATETIME, TOTALTIME1, RAWOUTPUT1, Pumpe1_1,
         LEAD (Pumpe1_1) OVER (ORDER BY datetime) next_,
         LAG (Pumpe1_1) OVER (ORDER BY datetime) priv_
    FROM table_)
SELECT DATETIME, TOTALTIME1, RAWOUTPUT1, Pumpe1_1
  FROM table2_
 WHERE (Pumpe1_1 != next_ OR Pumpe1_1 != priv_);
```

Comment: Nearly perfect, but I need only the rows when TRUE/FALSE changes. Please see my edit in the question. Thanks

Comment: I think the problem occurs when the `next_` and `prev_` both change so there is a condition needed like `If(Pumpe1_1 == TRUE && Pumpe1_1 == TRUE) Row.delete()` and also the other direction

Comment: Try to remove one of the condition i.e. use only one condition in where clause, `WHERE Pumpe1_1 != next_` only.

Comment: Or if you want only the switch from FALSE to TRUE then use condition `WHERE Pumpe1_1 = 'FALSE' and next_ = 'TRUE'`

Answer (score 1):

If this is how your data looks then simple distinct will work. You can also use max(your_date) and group by with more complex data as well as analytic functions - row_number() over...

```
SELECT distinct datetime, totaltime, rowoutput, pumpe1_1  FROM
(
SELECT '30.10.14' datetime, 53848 totaltime, 0 rowoutput, 'FALSE' pumpe1_1 FROM dual
UNION ALL
SELECT '30.10.14', 53848, 0, 'FALSE' FROM dual
UNION ALL
SELECT '30.10.14', 53848, 0, 'FALSE' FROM dual
UNION ALL
SELECT '30.10.14', 53847, 1, 'TRUE' FROM dual
UNION ALL
SELECT '30.10.14', 53847, 1, 'TRUE'  FROM dual
UNION ALL
SELECT '30.10.14', 53847, 1, 'TRUE'  FROM dual
)
/
```

Comment: Thanks but there are no duplicate values in my database because the example is not my hole database

Comment: Then you probably should post something similar to your data... And as i wrote, in this case max() or analytical will work. Good luck.